# Can't figure out why this code is causing a SIGSEGV when sending packet data

Tags: android, c++, c, sockets, networking

I'm writing some networking code on Android using POSIX sockets but I'm getting a weird SIGSEGV (Signal 11, code 1) when I make a call to sento. I've used the Tombstone trace to determine which line it is, but frankly I can't see what's wrong with it.

References to i_Socket and i_Server have been successful before this particular snippet. I should also mention that the strings are coming from marshaled strings from Mono/Unity.

```
// Set client informaion
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // We don't care IPv4 or IPv6
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // UDP Datagram packets

// Resolve server domain name
int res = getaddrinfo(server, TFTP_PORT, &hints, &i_ServerList);

// Check if we got a valid result
if (res != 0) {
    // Report error
    if (res == EAI_SYSTEM) 
        StreamingVideoPluginError("getaddrinfo");
    else {
        std::stringstream str;
        str << "error in getaddrinfo: " << gai_strerror(res);
    }
    return 1; // No such host
}

// Loop through all entries and bind to the first one we can
bool didBind = false;
for (auto i_Server = i_ServerList; i_Server != nullptr; i_Server = i_Server->ai_next) {
    // Try create the socket
    if ((i_Socket = socket(i_Server->ai_family, i_Server->ai_socktype, i_Server->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        // Display error
        StreamingVideoPluginError("client: socket creation failure");
        i_Socket = -1; // Reassert invalid socket
        continue;
    }
    else {
        // Binded a socket
        didBind = true;
        break;
    }
}

// Check if we could bind to a server
if (!didBind) {
    StreamingVideoPluginError("Failed to bind to a server.");
    return 2;
}

// Set socket options
struct timeval tv;
memset(&tv, 0, sizeof (struct timeval));
tv.tv_sec = 5; // 5 second timeout
if (setsockopt(i_Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof tv) == -1)
{
    std::stringstream str;
    str << "client: could not set timeout. errno =" << errno;
    StreamingVideoPluginError(str.str());
    return 3;
}


// Make the initial TFTP request
char tftp_buffer[512 + 4];
// Set the opcode to be read request
int packetLength = 0;
tftp_buffer[0] = 0;                   
tftp_buffer[1] = TFTP_RRQ;
packetLength = 2;


// Place filename
memcpy(&tftp_buffer[packetLength],tftpFileName, strlen(tftpFileName));
packetLength += strlen(tftpFileName);
tftp_buffer[packetLength] = 0; packetLength++;

// Set transfer type to be octet
memcpy(&tftp_buffer[packetLength], TRANSFER_TYPE, strlen(TRANSFER_TYPE));
packetLength += strlen(TRANSFER_TYPE);
tftp_buffer[packetLength] = 0; packetLength++;

std::stringstream str;
str << "Value of packetLength =" << packetLength;
StreamingVideoPluginLog(str.str());



// Send the TFTP request
if (sendto(i_Socket, tftp_buffer, packetLength, 0, i_Server->ai_addr, i_Server->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    // Could not send TFTP request
    StreamingVideoPluginError("client: could not send tftp request.");

    return 4;
}
```

Here is the output from NDK-Stack

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000018
Stack frame #00  pc 0001e544  /data/app-lib/com.imersia-2/PLUGINNAME.so (ImersiaTftpDa
taSource::Init(char const*, char const*)+1292)
Stack frame #01  pc 0001d428  /data/app-lib/NOPENOPENOPE-2/PLUGINNAME.so (std::priv::_S
TLP_alloc_proxy<char*, char, std::allocator<char> >::~_STLP_alloc_proxy()+16)
```

addr2line blames

```
C:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:472
```

Comment: just curious, what's the value of `packetLength` before calling `sendto()`?

Comment: You don't need all the `memcpy()'s`. You could use `sendmsg()` to do a gather-write, or just write the pieces directly from where they are one at a time. Don't move data unless you have to. Are you getting this SIGSEGV from *within* `sendto()` or while computing the arguments, e.g. `i_Server->ai_addr`? NB you should be comparing the result of `sendto()` to -1, and checking/displaying `errno` or `strerror[errno]` immediately, or calling `perror()`.

Comment: n3rd4n1, I've updated the code snippet. 

It's retuning 18, which is right. The test filename for the TFTP packet is "bunny.ogg".

Comment: How about the other parameters -- is i_Socket still valid at the time of call, or that i_Server is a valid pointer and it has valid fields? Maybe it will help if you post more code, showing at least the call to `socket`, `bind` and `listen` or `connect`.

Comment: I've uploaded the entire init function anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue. I was accidentally rebinding i_Server inside the for loop.

`for (auto i_Server = i_ServerList; i_Server != nullptr; i_Server = i_Server->ai_next) {`

should be

`for (i_Server = i_ServerList; i_Server != nullptr; i_Server = i_Server->ai_next) {`